# htaccess redirest

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

my pages on may site working perfectly until someone puts in the browser smothing like 
service.php/service.php . the page does not show any error , just an empty page. I would ht-access to redirect the user to  service.php.

thanks for the help

jeff

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your .htaccess should work if you can use mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /base/path
RewriteRule ^.*$ service.php
```